# Large-Scale SSH Key Management for PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

I have a need to create an SSH key management system. In our environment, we use OpenSSH on the server side, and we use PuTTY on the client side. I know how to use the PuTTYgen GUI to convert OpenSSH keys to PuTTY keys and vice versa. However, this is not practical when dealing with a large number of keys.

Does anybody know of command-line utilities that will perform these conversions and which I could call in a script or in some other way automate?

Comment: Why do *you* need to deal with the keys at all? They’re supposed to be secret, so the only thing that could need management are public keys.

Comment: _I_ need to deal with the keys because _I_ am the administrator and _I_ need to create an SSH key management system. Somebody needs to create, monitor, and destroy keys, and _I_ am not going to give my users cart blanche to do it themselves.

Comment: I will be looking at the proposed WinSCP solution shortly. Thanks, Martin.